# paracol and scaled fonts misaligned

Tags: line-spacing, scaling, polyglossia, paracol

I am using `pararcol` with english and arabic.  The arabic font is scaled up in size and this causes a misalignment of lines, not just within paragraphs, cumulatively, but also of the first paragraph under the section title.  The following MWE illustrates with [image: output] here.

How can I put extra spacing in the english text to keep better vertical alignment with the arabic?  And why is even the first line out of alignment?

Bonus: the section title stands outside `paracol`; if anyone has a better way of keeping the sections numbered correctly, please say!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in] {geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.4]{Times New Roman}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\section{Section\hfill\textarabic{قسم}}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn*}
First paragraph
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. 

\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\begin{Arabic}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة  كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة  

\end{Arabic}
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
Second paragraph. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 

\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\begin{Arabic}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة  كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
\end{Arabic}
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
Third paragraph. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 

\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\begin{Arabic}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة  كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
\end{Arabic}
\end{rightcolumn}


\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The vertical spacing is relative to font size. But why do you want to scale one font relative to the other?

Comment: because the arabic fonts are typically are smaller (all other things being equal); i.e. the size of the letters in arabic fonts compared to english fonts is unequal.

Comment: But in this case, they are not... so... ?

Comment: The height of Times New Roman letters above in Arabic is half what it 'should' be, according to my students here.  Even as I look at the display above, the arabic letters' height is too small by about 40%.  Width is ok, the height isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues in your setting.

1. The Arabic glyphs in Times New Roman (at least on my machine) live well above the baseline.
2. With the scaling factor you're using, the glyphs are too high (or deep) for the standard baseline skip, so `\lineskip` is used between them.

If I enlarge the baseline skip, alignment is good; the `\checkrule` command is just for showing my claims are true.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in] {geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.4]{Times New Roman}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\checkrule}[1][\textwidth]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule width #1 height 0pt depth 0.2pt}%
}

\linespread{1.4}

\begin{document}

\checkrule[2cm]\textarabic{قسم}

\section{Section\hfill\textarabic{قسم}}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn*}
\checkrule First paragraph
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. 

\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\begin{Arabic}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة  كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة  

\end{Arabic}
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\checkrule Second paragraph. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 

\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\begin{Arabic}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة  كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
\end{Arabic}
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\checkrule Third paragraph. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 

\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\begin{Arabic}
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة  كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة كلمة 
\end{Arabic}
\end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change the Arabic font, the alignment to the baseline is better; with

```
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}
```

I get

[image]

The setting to `\linespread` is a tentative one, you might be able to reduce the factor; you can set it locally in the `paracol` environment, but in this case remember to say

```
\begin{paracol}{2}
\linespread{1.4}\selectfont
...
```